# ¿Cómo sumar varios rangos en una consulta?

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta que me devuelve la suma de las imperfecciones en un rango determinado, pero quiero que me calcule también otros rangos. Lo que tengo ahora me devuelve esto más o menos:

| provincia | empresa | 0-4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Provincia | Empresa | 15 |

```
SELECT provincia.prov_nombre AS provincia, empresa.emp_nombre AS empresa, Sum(compra.por_imperfecciones) AS ["0-4"]
FROM provincia INNER JOIN (empresa INNER JOIN compra ON empresa.id = compra.empresa) ON provincia.id = empresa.provincia
WHERE compra.por_imperfecciones BETWEEN 0 AND 4

GROUP BY provincia.prov_nombre, empresa.emp_nombre;
```

Necesito que la consulta me devuelva más rangos. Por ejemplo:

| provincia | empresa | 0-4 | 5-10 | 10-20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Provincia | Empresa | 15 | 5 | 8 |

Las compras se almacenan en una tabla que guarda las imperfecciones que se registran cada vez que se hace una compra.

Cada vez que se registra una compra se define la cantidad de imperfecciones, lo que quiero es generar un informe que me diga por empresa la suma de las imperfecciones que se registraron en el rango de 0 a 4, en el rango de 5 a 10 y en el rango de 10 a 20.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. No me queda muy claro lo que quieres hace. ¿Qué son imperfecciones? ¿Qué otros rangos deseas calcular? Intenta describir más la pregunta y la estructura de la tabla por si alguien más que pueda ayudarte también se vea con dudas.

Comment: Hola. Las imperfecciones son valores que se registran a la hora de hacer la compra, lo que quiero es poder sumar todos estos valores por rango, es decir, saber la suma de las imperfecciones que cayeron en el rango de 0 a 4, en el de 5 a 10, etc. No se si me explico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es colocar un `if` en cada columna del rango que quieres, esto hace que se verifique por cada resultado obtenido, en caso de que este en el rango de la condición suma `compra.por_imperfecciones`, en caso contrario suma 0, esto solo para cumplir con la sintaxis de `if`, asi evitas una condición final puesto que en el `where` se aplica a todo el query, de este modo quedaría algo así:

```sql
SELECT 
provincia.prov_nombre AS provincia
,empresa.emp_nombre AS empresa
,sum(if(compra.por_imperfecciones between 0 AND 4,compra.por_imperfecciones,0)) AS "0-4"
,sum(if(compra.por_imperfecciones between 5 AND 10,compra.por_imperfecciones,0)) AS "5-10"
,sum(if(compra.por_imperfecciones between 10 AND 20,compra.por_imperfecciones,0)) AS "10-20"
FROM ...
GROUP BY provincia.prov_nombre , empresa.emp_nombre;
```

Comment: Genial, exactamente lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias.